# RavenDb - Query on a field that is aggregated in the Reduce function

Tags: mapreduce, ravendb

I have a set of documents that represent some workitems:

```csharp
public class WorkItem
{
    public string Id {get;set;
    public string DocumentId { get; set; }
    public string FieldId { get; set; }
    public bool IsValidated { get; set; }
}

public class ExtractionUser
{
    public string Id {get;set;}
    public string Name {get;set;}
    public string[] AssignedFields {get;set;}
}
```

A user has access to a set of FieldIds. I need to query the WorkItems based on this set of fields and get out a status per document:

```csharp
public class UserWorkItems
{
    public string DocumentId { get; set; }
    public int Validated { get; set; }
    public int Total { get; set; }
}
```

The query I'm a after is this:

```csharp
using (var session = RavenDb.OpenSession())
{
    string[] userFields = session.Load<User>("users/1").Fields;
    session.Query<WorkItem>()
        .Where(w => w.FieldId.In(userFields))
        .GroupBy(w => w.DocumentId)
        .Select(g => new
        {
            DocumentId = g.Key,
            Validated = g.Where(w => w.IsValidated).Count(),
            Total = g.Count()
        }).Skip(page * perPage).Take(perPage)
        .ToArray();
}
```

I have tried creating a Map/Reduce index but the main problem was that I need to be able to apply a filter on the FieldId which is not included in the Reduce output since it is the property that is counted.

I have also tried doing a simple Map index on the FieldId for the query part and a TransformResults to perform the GroupBy - but since the paging is applied before the TransformResults the pages and totals reflect the documents before grouping which is not good.

Then i've tried to use a Multi Map index that maps users and their fields collection and also maps the workitems and field then try to reduce the result to what i wanted. I've created [a gist](https://gist.github.com/4024002) with the index definition. The reduce part involves a group by field and then multiple SelectMany and a final GroupBy and Select. The index has been accepted by raven, but i does not return any results. I'm a bit stuck at the Multi Map index as i don't know how i could actually debug it.

I guess in the end my problem could be reduced (pun intended) to how to query on a "reduced" field?

Any ideas how I could achieve such a functionality? Are there any other options I could explore beside Map/MultiMap/Reduce/TransformResults?

**UPDATE**: While reading [Ayende's Map Reduce post](http://ayende.com/blog/4435/map-reduce-a-visual-explanation) I realised I'm approaching mapreduce wrong. Still looking for a solution ...

**UPDATE 2**: After a bit more research I've ended up with this index which looks like what i want to do but does not return any data (the index was defined directly in the studio):

Map:

```csharp
from user in docs
where user["@metadata"]["Raven-Entity-Name"] == "ExtractionUsers"
from field in user.AssignedFields
from item in docs
where item["@metadata"]["Raven-Entity-Name"] == "WorkItems" && item.FieldId == field
select new {
    UserId = user.Id,
    DocumentId = item.DocumentId,
    Validated = item.Status=="Validated"? 1: 0,
    Count = 1
}
```

Reduce:

```csharp
from r in results
group r by new { r.UserId , r.DocumentId } into g
select new {
    UserId = g.Key.UserId,
    DocumentId = g.Key.DocumentId,
    Validated = g.Sum(d => d.Validated),
    Count = g.Sum(d => d.Count),
}
```

The idea is to try to map in the index all the documents, and link from Users to Fields and to WorkItems.

Comment: Can you describe your structure in a bit more detail (the `User` and the `Field` classes)?

Comment: I've added the structure of the User ( ExtractionUser ) class - it is just an Id, Name and AssignedFields collection. The field only exists as an Id which is the field name - so no actual class there. One thing to consider is that the AssignedFields are subject to change in time as user get new fields assigned to them - so denormalizing that information in the workitem is not an option.

Comment: That updated index you posted isn't going to work, you can't have 2 "from x in docs" inside an index like that. If you want to index across multiple types take a look at Multi-Map, http://ravendb.net/kb/11/querying-unlike-documents-using-a-multi-map-index

Comment: @MattWarren Thanks, I'm trying to use a multi map reduce now, but the reduce part is not returning all the results. I have created a [gist here](https://gist.github.com/4031390)

Comment: I've posted some more information on the [mailinglist](https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!topic/ravendb/GzbHcdQHA1c)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After a week I've managed to solve the problem. I've took a slightly different (less relational) approach that is a simple and seems to work fine. Here are the details in case somebody else has this kind of problems:

I group the WorkItems by DocumentId and put in a collection the Validated and the NonValidated fields. The result of the map reduce looks like this:

```csharp
public class Result
{
    public string DocumentId { get; set; }
    public string[] ValidatedFields { get; set; }
    public string[] ReadyFields { get; set; }
}
```

The **Map** function looks like this:

```csharp
Map = items => items.Select(i => new
{
    DocumentId = i.DocumentId,
    ValidatedFields = i.IsValidated ? new string[] { i.FieldId } : new string[0],
    ReadyFields = !i.IsValidated ? new string[] { i.FieldId } : new string[0]
});
```

And the **Reduce** :

```csharp
Reduce = result => result
    .GroupBy(i => i.DocumentId)
    .Select(g => new
    {
        DocumentId = g.Key,
        ValidatedFields = g.SelectMany(i => i.ValidatedFields),
        ReadyFields = g.SelectMany(i => i.ReadyFields)
    });
```

To query the index I now use the following expression:

```csharp
User user = session.Load<User>("users/1");
var result = session.Query<WorkItem, UserWorkItemIndex>()
    .As<UserWorkItemIndex.Result>()
    .Where(d => d.ValidatedFields.Any(f => f.In(user.AssignedFields)))
    .ToArray();
```

The only thing i need to do client side is count only the fields that belong to the user.

There is also a [gist](https://gist.github.com/4051366) with the solution.

Answer (score 0):

**First, a disclaimer:** I've never worked with RavenDB before in a real system, but I read some articles, watched some videos and really like the idea behind it. I thought of this problem as an interesting exercise. So, this is approach may not be ideal; comments and improvements are welcome.

My idea is that an index has to be created on the `WorkItems` collection to include these fields:

- `DocumentId` (because that's what we'll group by in the end)
- `FieldId` (because that's the field we'll filter by)
- `ValidatedCount` (the count of records that have `IsValidated` = true)
- `TotalCount`

After creating this index, we can query it with the `.Where(x => x.FieldId.In(userFields))` filter and get back a set of results that have the structure described above.

In order to get the final result, we need to perform on more grouping by `DocumentId` on these results.

The code I came up with is this:

#### The index definition

```csharp
public class WorkItems_ValidationStatistics :
    AbstractIndexCreationTask<WorkItem, WorkItems_ValidationStatistics.ReduceResult>
{
    public class ReduceResult
    {
        public string DocumentId { get; set; }
        public string FieldId { get; set; }
        public int ValidatedCount { get; set; }
        public int TotalCount { get; set; }
    }

    public WorkItems_ValidationStatistics()
    {
        Map = workItems =>
              from workItem in workItems
              select new
                    {
                        workItem.DocumentId,
                        workItem.FieldId,
                        ValidatedCount = workItem.IsValidated ? 1 : 0,
                        TotalCount = 1
                    };

        Reduce = results =>
                 from result in results
                 group result by new { result.FieldId, result.DocumentId }
                     into g
                     select new
                        {
                            g.Key.DocumentId,
                            g.Key.FieldId,
                            ValidatedCount = g.Sum(x => x.ValidatedCount),
                            TotalCount = g.Sum(x => x.TotalCount)
                        };
    }
}
```

#### The code to create the index in the database:

```csharp
public void CreateIndex()
{
    using (var store = CreateDocumentStore())
    {
        IndexCreation.CreateIndexes(
            typeof(WorkItems_ValidationStatistics).Assembly, store);
    }
}
```

***Note:** Alternatively, you can create the index directly in the RavenDB Management Studio*

#### The code that queries the index and does the final aggregation:

```csharp
public void GetWorkItemStatisticsGroupedByDocumentId()
{
    using (var store = CreateDocumentStore())
    using (var documentSession = store.OpenSession())
    {
        var userFields = new[] { "fields/11", "fields/13" };

        var items = documentSession
            .Query<WorkItems_ValidationStatistics.ReduceResult, WorkItems_ValidationStatistics>()
            .Where(x => x.FieldId.In(userFields))
            .ToList();

        var results = items
            .GroupBy(x => x.DocumentId)
            .Select(g => new
                {
                    DocumentId = g.Key,
                    ValidatedCount = g.Sum(x => x.ValidatedCount),
                    TotalCount = g.Sum(x => x.TotalCount)
                });

        foreach (var r in results)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("DocId={0}: validated: {1}/{2}", 
                r.DocumentId, r.ValidatedCount, r.TotalCount);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but this will perform the grouping on the client, and since i have potentially a large number of workitems ( fields per documents ) it is not a viable option. The first method I've tried where I've used a Map for the FieldId and a TransformResult to do the grouping does the same thing but with grouping on the server BUT it applies the paging before the TransformResult which is not ok in my case as I need to paginate the final grouped result, not the work items.

Comment: @IulianMargarintescu You're right; for some reason I assumed that the records grouped on the client would be fewer, but I was wrong in this assumption. I'll think of a way to fix this.

Comment: The main problem with grouping on the client or on the server in the TransformResult is that paging will be performed on the data before grouping so it will not be easy to handle.

Comment: @IulianMargarintescu correct. I've been thinking of another way to solve this, but have no other idea so far. I've been stuck in the Dynamic Query page for a while... :)

Comment: thanks for the time invested. I've also posted some more details on the [raven mailinglist](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/ravendb/GzbHcdQHA1c). The thing is that I can work around this since I have full control over the app, but I have found this to be a great opportunity to get deep into advanced RavenDB ;-)